# How to retrieve the current animation playing from Animator?

Tags: unity-game-engine

#### I want to check whether an Animation is playing or not so can you help me retrieve the name of the current Animation playing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AIM : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator play;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {  
      //Debug.Log(play.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0).clip.name);
    }
}
```

[Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo.html)
I tried `play.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0).clip.name` but it throws an error :

`'AnimatorClipInfo[]' does not contain a definition for 'clip'`

Comment: Did you even look at the docs? They include this very answer

Comment: @BugFinder I tried `play.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0).clip.name` but it's giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are accessing the array. GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0) returns an array. You need to access the array element to get is info, like this:

```
play.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)[0].clip.name
```